# Is the lawyer in on the scam?

Tags: plot-explanation, sleepers

In the film [Sleepers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117665/) (1996), is Danny Snyder (Dustin Hoffman) "in" on the scam taking place, or does he just assume that King Benny is trying to protect the boys, and that's why Benny has given him a list of all the proper questions to be asked to ensure that Tommy and John will be found innocent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I watched the movie, but I don't remember a single hint of him being aware of the scam. As I wrote in the answer to [your other question on this movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24330/5589), Danny was manipulated by Michael.